# How do I get this simple C test program for loading modules to work?

Tags: c, gcc, dlopen, lvalue, dlsym

I was going to use dlopen, and dlsym on linux to make these two source files work:

```
 #include <dlfcn.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int *(func)(void);

     func=dlsym( dlopen("/home/noah/tmp/libmod.so.1", RTLD_LAZY), "func");

     printf("%d\n", *func());
     return 0;
}
```

and:

```
int func()
{
return 42;
}
```

but when I compile the first one, it keeps saying:

> main.c:9: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

edit:
I tried adding a cast, and making it a function pointer, but now it says: 
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
main.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to`dlsym'

Comment: +1 for being a well written question

Answer (score 4):

Your declaration of `func` is confused:

```
int *(func)(void);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int *func(void);
```

so you're just giving the compiler a prototype for `func` without declaring a variable; the error occurs because a function is not a valid lvalue; however, a *pointer* to a function is a valid lvalue so you want this:

```
int (*func)(void);
```

And then your `printf` should be this:

```
printf("%d\n", func());
```

You'll also need to cast the return from `dlsym` to be strictly conforming to standard C:

```
func = (int (*)(void))dlsym(dlopen("/home/noah/tmp/libmod.so.1", RTLD_LAZY), "func");
```

A `void*` pointer can be silently upgraded to any other pointer type except a pointer to a function; `gcc -pedantic`, for example, will warn that "ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and ‘void *’" without the cast. I don't have a copy of the standard handy (but someone around here certainly does) so I can't quote chapter and verse but caf is correct on this point (thanks caf).

And you also want to bookmark [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Comment: Since `dlsym()` returns `void *`, you also need to explicitly cast to the function pointer type: `func = (int (*)(void))dlsym(...`

Comment: @caf: The cast is needed for strict conformance so I'll add that, thanks. With `gcc -pedantic`, for example, you'll get "ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and ‘void *’" without the cast.

Comment: now it says: main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
main.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlsym'

Comment: @noah: You need to link in the right library, add `-ldl` at the end of your compile command for `main.c`, something like `cc -o main main.c -ldl`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't really do what you are attempting

but   it should be int (func*)()

and the printf should be func()

but you can't assign the dlsym with all its parameters as a function pointer

hint.... the function pointer "func" is just a pointer, it has no state, its just a memory address

and you shouldn't provide a function called func.....   as you are making a pointer called func.     you could make a function  "int test_function(){ return 42; }

then in main   go  func = test_function;    just to test using the function pointer

Comment: if dlsym doesn't give a function pointer than what the heck does it give?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `*func()`

```
printf("%d\n", func());
```

will be ok, cause func() will return the int, and you try to get dereference (*) of integer

look at precedence of operators ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++))